# Add headers to JSON using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm looking to add `text` header to a JSON I'm tryind to send via JS, the actual method put the text in doubles quotes, here's what I expect by adding a header:

> {"text": "URL.com"}

```js
function getData() {
    var input = $("#user_input").val();
    var jsonencod = JSON.stringify(input);
    alert(jsonencod);
}
```

```html
Enter a URL

<input type=" text"id="user_input">
<button onclick="getData()">Go!</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking, but doublequotes are required in JSON for string keys and values ?

Comment: @adeneo how to add {"text": } header ?

Comment: So you're asking how to add a ***key***? If so, the answer below seem to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should give you the output you are looking for.

Simply change `input` to `{"text": input}` to product the desired JSON.

```js
function getData() {
    var input = $("#user_input").val();
    var jsonencod = JSON.stringify({"text": input});
    alert(jsonencod);
}
```

```html
Enter a URL

<input type=" text"id="user_input">
<button onclick="getData()">Go!</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```